# DomPDF html and css file to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, dompdf

I am currently working on a HTML file, but when I open this in my browser I want that DomPDf creates a PDF in the browser instead of opening the HTML page.

Currently I have this code, but I only see the HTML.

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http:// www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
<head> 
<title></title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen" /> 
</head> 


<body> 
<div id="row0">div 1</div> 
<div id="row1">div 2</div>

<?php 
require_once("d/dompdf_config.inc.php"); 
$dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean()); 
$dompdf->render(); 
file_put_contents('customers.pdf', $dompdf->output()); 
?> 


</body> 
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 10 questions * 0 accepted answers = 0 incentive

Answer (score -3):

You should put the PHP at the very end, after `</html>`